# What is the Best Oracle Driver (THIN) for Oracle 11G

Tags: performance, oracle, hibernate, oracle11g, driver

We are using Data source based connection pooling in JBoss. We are using JDK 1.6.
What is the recommended (stable and Bug/leakage-free) Oracle Driver (THIN) for Oracle 11G?
We are trying to use Hibernate 3.5 with Spring MVC. Where Can I download that driver.
Is there any way to track leakage at Oracle Driver level? 
Is ojdbc6.jar[this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html) from Oracle Corp a recommended one?

Answer (score 1):

The latest driver available for the free download from Oracle web site (11.2.0.2.0) appears to have a broken DST handling: [Was daylight savings time handling broken in Oracle JDBC driver version 11.2.0.2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687454/was-daylight-savings-time-handling-broken-in-oracle-jdbc-driver-version-11-2-0-2) .

You might want to get the patched one, if you have support contract with Oracle or check the bugs fixed in the latest release and see if bugs fixed to bugs introduced ratio justifis going back to 11.2.0.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

This is the main download site for Oracle's JDBC driver:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html

Comment: Thanks, It is same as the link that I referred in the question. Question if it is bug-free and mature enough to be used given the context of performance.

Comment: Well "bug-free" is relative, isn't it? We are using the Oracle driver in several large websites without problems.

Comment: True. which one you are using? is it ojdbc5 or ojdbc6.jar?

Comment: ojdbc6.jar because we exclusively use Java6