# Oracle timestamp sql

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I run

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('8-JUN-20 10.30.05.024000000 PM','DD-Mon-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM') FROM dual;
```

return this:

```
08/06/20 10:30:05.024000000 PM
```

But I want is that return this:

```
08-JUN-20 10.30.05.024000000 PM
```

Comment: it already returns what you want : *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=52a2206c47d375d5828798d2a389cdc2)*

Comment: Great! But why in my local machine in Oracle SQL Developer doesn't show like that? It doesn't matter?

Comment: It doesn't matter. If you insist, alter session and change timestamp format mask.

Comment: Do you want a timestamp (which your client can format - check your `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` setting in preferences); or a string representation of a timestamp? As you already have a string to pass into `to_timestamp()`, presumably the former.

Comment: maybe its your client changing the date format , look into your client settings

Comment: [Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51269015/266304); I'm sure there's a proper duplicate question out there somewhere...

Comment: A TIMESTAMP and a DATE are internal binary formats.  Everything about them that is displayed on your screen is _necessarily_ a character representation of the timestamp or date -- the result of either an implicit or explicit TO_CHAR() function applied to the TIMESTAMP or DATE.  If you don't do an explicit TO_CHAR() the implicit one used by oracle will format the output according to the session NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT or NLS_DATE_FORMAT settings.  These settings are under the control of your client session.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67939144/convert-timestamp-in-oracle-sql

Answer (score 0):

TO_TIMESTAMP returns a TIMESTAMP datatype. Are you looking to show a date/time variable with a specific date format? If so, use TO_CHAR with desired date/time format, i.e:

```
Select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM') from dual;
```