# Convert timestamp in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Column timestamp format as

```
10-AUG-16 02.35.36.000000 PM EUROPE/LONDON
```

Expected output

```
10-AUG-16 02.35.36.000000 AM +01:00
```

However,

```
TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ (timestampvalue,'YYYY-MM-DDHH:MI:SSTZH:TZM')
```

isn't returning required format.

Appreciate your inputs, TIA

Comment: "Format' is only relevant for the display of a date/timestamp, not how it is stored in a column.  Please show the table DDL.  and what does "isn't returning required format" mean? Is there an error?  Please provide the details. Thanks

Comment: [Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51269015/266304) - a column doesn't have a human-readable format, your client is applying a format for display. Are you trying to convert your actual timestamp value to a string which shows TZ offset instead of region?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67938539/oracle-timestamp-sql