# Different Timezone on Server and Database

Tags: database, oracle, server

We have an app that is being used by clients on different location.
The app timezone is based on user location. 
We have an API that is deployed on a server which the timezone is UTC, and the database is in CST. 
This is causing issues when it comes to ordering parts. The code I have is:

```
total(case when (wo.Order <= current_timestamp + interval '1' day)
```

current_timestamp is in UTC, wo.Order is in CST, and user is in different timezone based on location. What is the best way to approach this problem? Should I make the server & DB same time or do I need to locate user location?

Comment: What is the data type of `wo.Order`?  `date`?  `timestamp`?  `timestamp with time zone`?  `timestamp with local time zone`?

Comment: I should have clarified. wo.Order is timestamp: 10-SEP-12 15.49.03

Comment: "database is in CST" ... why? Only use UTC in your backend and let the client convert that in the timezone they want.

Comment: I am guessing the DB is taking local time.

Comment: It depends on many factors, maybe this answer will clear up this problem a bit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22305466/oracle-date-compare-broken-because-of-dst/22313422#22313422